# Designing a form with conditionally required text input

Tags: forms

I have a very simple form, which can be used to get a preliminary delivery quote. It simply has 1 text field, and looks like so:

[image]

This should be integrated in ads website, so pick - up location is provided dynamically.

All is good if pick up location is in different town. My problem is... how best to convey to user that if delivery location, is same town as pick up location, that they don't need to enter anything in the `Delivery location` field?

Should this be structured in a different way altogether, bearing in mind the fact that they don't need to enter anything provided delivery and pick-up is in same location.

I cannot make any assumptions about which scenario (deliver within same town, or to different town) would be more common. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a clear indication that location is the same, but let user change it:
[image]

I would leave them with no option to rollback to "Same as Pickup" because it makes layout less crowded, but if you notice that this option is valuable you may add a link to "undo" or "cancel".